# How can I add a new line at the end of the output? (Linux help)

Tags: linux, echo, command-line-arguments, tr

i am using this code

```
cut -c1 | tr -d '\n'
```

to basically take and print out the first letter of every line. the problem is, I need a new line at the end, but only at the end, after the word "caroline" (these are the content of the **testfile**

Cannot use AWK, basename, grep, egrep, fgrep or rgrep

Answer (score 1):

Use echo

```
echo $( cut -c1 | tr -d '\n' ) \n
```

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Comment: @lina: If this solved your question, be certain to mark it as the accepted answer once you’re able to.

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -c1 | tr -d '\n'; echo -e '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `awk` utility, something like following:-

```
awk -F\| '$1 > 0 { print substr($1,1,1)}' testfile.txt
```